# Failing to create a Jenkins job via Ansible with jenkins_job on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am trying to use the *jenkins_job* module in Ansible and it keeps throwing up the error `Unable to create job, Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.`

I trigger this error with the following task that lives in a file tasks/add_job.yml called by main.yml:

```
- name: Install CloudBees Folder for {{ item }}
  jenkins_job:
    config: "{{ lookup('template', 'config.xml.j2') }}"
    name: {{ item }}
    password: "{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
    url: "http://{{ jenkins_hostname }}:{{ jenkins_http_port }}"
    user: "{{ jenkins_admin_username }}"
```

This task is called multiple times by tasks/add_jobs.yml like so:

```
- name: Include job array via vars.
  include_vars:
    file: jobs.yml

- name: Install jobs.
  include: add_job.yml
  with_items: "{{ jenkins_jobs }}"
```

The var file looks like this:

```
jenkins_jobs:
  - Job1
  - Job2
```

My config file is in the templates directory and looks like this (I tried many different XML files and ended up trying to use [this config](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/b89cb956092e6f28d16010dc887ee2dc46e7855b/test/integration/roles/test_jenkins_job/templates/config.xml.j2) from the ansible GitHub project:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
      <strategy class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
        <daysToKeep>1</daysToKeep>
        <numToKeep>20</numToKeep>
        <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
        <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
      </strategy>
    </jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitbucket.GitBucketProjectProperty plugin="gitbucket@0.8">
      <linkEnabled>false</linkEnabled>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitbucket.GitBucketProjectProperty>
  </properties>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders/>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

I run this targeting a local Vagrant configured via:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/xenial64'
  config.vm.network(:private_network, ip: '192.168.99.101')
  config.vm.network(:forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8080)
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |provider|
    provider.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--name', 'ansible-jenkins']
    provider.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cpus', '2']
    provider.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--memory', '2048']
    provider.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nictype1', 'virtio']
  end
end
```

Prior to getting this error I had lots of problems even getting jenkins_job to run as it kept complaining about missing dependencies, so here is my list of package installations on the Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

```
jenkins_job_dependencies:
  - build-essential
  - python-pip
  - python3-pip
  - libffi-dev
  - libssl-dev
  - libxml2-dev
  - libxslt1-dev
  - python-dev
  - python3-dev
  - python-lxml
  - python3-lxml
  - python-jenkins
  - python3-jenkins
  - python3-venv
  - git
```

Here is the `-vvvv` output

```
fatal: [local-vagrant]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "config": "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<project>\n  <actions/>\n  <description></description>\n  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>\n  <properties>\n    <jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>\n      <strategy class=\"hudson.tasks.LogRotator\">\n        <daysToKeep>1</daysToKeep>\n        <numToKeep>20</numToKeep>\n        <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>\n        <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>\n      </strategy>\n    </jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>\n    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitbucket.GitBucketProjectProperty plugin=\"gitbucket@0.8\">\n      <linkEnabled>false</linkEnabled>\n    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitbucket.GitBucketProjectProperty>\n  </properties>\n  <scm class=\"hudson.scm.NullSCM\"/>\n  <canRoam>true</canRoam>\n  <disabled>false</disabled>\n  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>\n  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>\n  <triggers/>\n  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>\n  <builders/>\n  <publishers/>\n  <buildWrappers/>\n</project>\n",
            "enabled": null,
            "name": "Job1",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "state": "present",
            "token": null,
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "user": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Unable to create job, Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration. for http://localhost:8080"
}
```

I've tried many permutations of the xml declaration: including it, removing it, using utf-16 etc and none seem to work. Any pointers would be gratefully received. I appreciate there are numerous other ways of creating jobs via Ansible (cUrl, cli etc) and I am in the process of porting my project to use job-dsl plugin but it would be really neat if I could get this working using an 'out-of-the-box' Ansible module

ok...so that was my first question on StackOverflow...apologies if I got anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the ansible_python_interpreter which was set to `/usr/bin/python3` in my hosts inventory. When I set it to `/usr/bin/python` the problem disappeared. Yay....

...Except that was only half the story. When I destroyed and recreated my VM it failed on the first step as the Ubuntu 16.04LTS does not have `/usr/bin/python` it only has `/usr/bin/python3`.

I didn't want to create symlinks or do virtenv stuff...so I just set the ansible_python_interpreter to `/usr/bin/python` *after* I installed python2-dev apt package but *before* I ran the jenkins_script module. Then I set it back again after running my scripts.

```
# Truncated playbook for brevity...
- name: Install dependency
  package: "name=python-dev state=present"

- name: Set the python interpreter to the symlink (which points at version 2.7)
  set_fact:
    ansible_python_interpreter: '/usr/bin/python'

- name: Do script thing.
  jenkins_script:
    script: "{{ script_var }}"
    user: "{{ jenkins_username }}"
    password: "{{ jenkins_password }}"
  changed_when: true
  no_log: True

- name: Set the python interpreter back to version 3
  set_fact:
    ansible_python_interpreter: '/usr/bin/python3'
```

If I could find out where the source code for jenkins_script module is I would do a pull request to fix the underlying problem but alas I can't figure out where that is...